# Worklight 6.1.0.1 Fix Pack Contents Definitive List

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When looking at the contents of [Version 6.1.0 Fix Pack 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041452), it doesn't appear to list [PI06519](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI06519) as one of it's constituents, yet when applying the fix pack in a bid to address the slow start up issue, it appears to fix the problem.

Is this supposed to be the definitive list of the contents of the fix pack and is simply an oversight, or should I be looking somewhere else for the full contents of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem with listing this APAR in the list of fixes which has yet to be resolved.

Here is a copy of the fixed APARs in Worklight 6.1.0.1:

```
Changes since: 6.1.0.0
Fixes (APARs):
PI12596 A HYBRID APPLICATION MAY FORCE CLOSE OR FAIL TO CAPTURE DATA WHEN RETURNING FROM THE CAMERA VIEW.
PI12471 RICH PAGE EDITOR'S PERFORMANCE SUFFERS WHILE TYPING.
PI12337 WHITE LINE AT THE BOTTOM IN IOS 7.1
PI11962 SECURITY ISSUE WITH WORKLIGHT CONSOLE
PI11561 STUCK IN A DIALOG ENDLESS LOOP IN ECLIPSE WORKLIGHT PREFERENCES
PI11502 EVENT LISTENERS ATTACHED WHEN CONNECT() IS INVOKED BUT NEVER UNBOUND.
PI11350 IN THE WL STUDIO WITH BUILT-IN SERVER, THE FEATURE OPEN WORKLIGHT CONSOLE DOES NOT START THE SERVER AUTOMATICALLY.
PI11168 WORKIGHT PAGE DOES NOT RESPOND TO CHANGING RICH PAGE EDITOR DEVICE ORIENTATION TO PORTRAIT
PI10959 JSONSTORE FAILS TO REMOVE ALL DOCS IN THE DOC ARRAY WHEN A DOC ARRAY IS PASSED
PI10818 FAILURE WHEN DEPLOYING WORKLIGHT APPLICATION ON WORKLIGHT  PUREAPPLICATION PATTERN WHEN SCALING POLICY IS IN EFFECT
PI10775 SERVER CONFIGURATION TOOL DEPLOYMENT CAN NOT PROCEED WHEN USING DB2 DATABASE IF DB2 INSTANCE OWNER ID DOES NOT HAVE SSH ACCESS
PI10398 PROBLEM CUSTOMIZING TIMEOUTS WITH WL.CLIENT.CONNECT API.
PI10149 MOBILE BROWSER SIMULATOR IS BLOCKED IN BROWSER WHEN USING  ORACLE JAVA 7 UPDATE 51 WITH "HIGH" SECURITY SETTING
PI10127 NATIVEPAGE FEATURE DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY ON WINDOWS PHONE 8
PI09913 WORKLIGHT UNDER HIGH VOLUMES SHOWS MEMORY INCREASE WHEN REPORTING ENABLED
PI09863 IF REMOVING THE OPTIONAL FIELD "BADGE", AN ERROR IS RECEIVED: "MANDATORY FIELD 'BADGE' NOT FOUND."
PI09770 IOS PUSH NOTIFICATION ERROR AFTER UPGRADING OR APPLYING FIX
PI09711 [WINDOWS 8] - CANNOT OPEN A WL.SIMPLEDIALOG AFTER IT WAS OPENED AND CLOSED
PI09666 ADDING ENVIRONMENT WAITS ON "BUILD PREVIEW PAGES"
PI09569 WHEN BACKEND IS STALE/SLOW UNDER LOAD THEN GOES BACK TO NORMAL SERVER CANNOT RECOVER UNTIL RESTART
PI09530 ADAPTER INVOCATION IS FAILING IN IOS 5 IN WORKLIGHT 6.1  ENVIRONMENT.
PI09432 CALLING ACQUIREPOSITION AFTER STARTACQUISITION HAS BEEN CALLED WITH A GEO POLICY, MAY NOT ACTIVATE TRIGGERS FOR NEW POSITIONS.
PI09373 RARELY, ON NATIVE ANDROID, MULTIPLE SUCCESS CALLBACK EXECUTIONS CAN TAKE PLACE FOR WLDEVICE.ACQUIREGEOPOSITION.
PI09372 IN NATIVE ANDROID, USE OF THE WLGEOACQUISITIONPOLICY MUST BE DONE IN A LOOPER THREAD.
PI09370 WHEN USING GEO DWELL TRIGGERS, WLGEOFAILURECALLBACK INSTANCES MAY BE EXECUTED AFTER WLDEVICE.STOPACQUISITION() IS CALLED.
PI09356 ADAPT APPLICATION CENTER PUBLISH SHORTCUT TO HANDLE XAP FILES
PI09349 WHEN IMPORTING THE IBMAPPCENTER HYBRID PROJECT, AN INCORRECT WARNING SUGGESTS TO INCREASE THE VERSION
PI09326 APPCENTER OTA INSTALLER: TITLE TRUNCATION ON DETAILS VIEW
PI09325 APPCENTER CLIENT TABLET PORTRAIT, BUTTON TRUNCATION ON DETAILS VIEW
PI09324 APPCENTER CLIENT IOS: DATES APPEAR A PHONE NUMBERS
PI09323 APPCENTER OTA CAN START IN TABLET MODE ON A PHONE IN LANDSCAPE ORIENTATION.
PI09321 WORKLIGHT APPCENTER MOBILE CLIENT: AFTER SENDING A REVIEW, THE APP IS MISSING FROM LISTS IF ITS POSITION CHANGED
PI09315 APPLICATION CENTER MOBILE CLIENT ON TABLET: SOME APPLICATIONS MAY NOT BE DISPLAYED IN CATALOG.
PI09233 WORKLIGHT SERVER THROWS EXCEPTION WHEN RE-AUTHENTICATING WITH THE ANTIXSRF REALM
PI09224 WHEN MIGRATING A PROJECT FROM WORKLIGHT 6.0 TO 6.1, AN ERROR OCCURS STATING THAT THE UPGRADE PATH IS NOT SUPPORTED
PI09029 IOS APP LINK FAILS WHEN SETTING IOS DEPLOYMENT TARGET TO 7.0
PI08960 WL RUNTIME LOGS THE FULL CLIENT REQUEST WHEN AN ERROR HAPPENS
PI08819 INCORRECT DATA MAY RETURNED WHEN SUBSCRIBING/UNSUBSCRIBING FOR SMS EVENTS
PI08807 DESIGN PANE FOR JSF PAGES FAILS TO UPDATE
PI08806 INACCURATE JSP VALIDATION
PI08789 FIX WLJQ.JS TO SUPPORT WINDOWS 8 AND WINDOWS PHONE 8
PI08777 "ITMS-SERVICES" PROTOCOL DOES NOT WORK
PI08689 INCORRECT DATA MAY BE RETURNED FROM THE SERVER TO THE APPLICATION
PI08685 IMPROVE PERFORMANCE WHEN USING THE IBM SDK FOR JAVA
PI08632 APP CLIENT CLOSES WHEN CONNECTING TO SERVER WITH ANALYTICS  ENABLED.
PI08609 CLUSTER SYNC TASK REPEATEDLY TRIES TO DEPLOY OLD APP FROM THE DB TO A NEW PROJECT
PI08601 WL.SERVER.INVOKEHTTP WITH DELETE METHOD DOESN'T ACCEPT QUERY PARAM
PI08583 BLACK LINE APPEARS AT TOP OF SPLASH SCREEN ON IPAD RUNNING IOS7
PI08580 ECLIPSE CRASHES WHEN OPENING WORKLIGHT APPLICATION FRAMEWORK VIEW.HTML ON WINDOWS
PI08574 FAILURE TO MIGRATE WORKLIGHT PRE-5.0.5.0 APPLICATIONS TO WORKLIGHT 6.1.0.0
PI08511 OLD LTPA TOKEN IS BEING USED WHEN USER LOGIN AGAIN WITHIN A MINUTE OF LOGOUT
PI08189 ERROR WHEN CONNECTING TO SERVER AFTER SETTING APP TO ACTIVE IN THE CONSOLE.
PI08127 SLOW SERVER PERFORMANCE AND REPEATED DATABASE QUERIES WHEN REMOTE DISABLE IS ENABLED
PI07660 MISSING API GETDEFAULTMOBILECONFIGURATION4ANDROID_IOS() IN LOGINCONFIGURATIONSERVICE INTERFACE
PI07549 SHELL COMPONENT CHANGES ARE NOT SHOWN PROPERLY IN BROWSER DURING PREVIEW
PI07263 SCREEN TURNS BLACK ON IPAD DURING DIRECT UPDATE
PI07256 INAPPBROWSER NOT ABLE TO OPEN LOCAL URL LINKS ON ANDROID 4.4
PI06943 DIRECT UPDATE NOTIFICATION WHEN NONE AVAILABLE, THEN FAILS UPON UPDATE ATTEMPT
PI06828 ANT DEPLOMENT TASKS DON'T WORK WHEN CONSOLE IS PROTECTED WITH LTPA AUTHENTICATION
PI06652 DIRECT UPDATE ALLOWS USERS TO KEEP USING OUTDATED VERSIONS.
PI06586 INCORRECT PUSH NOTIFICATION RECEIVED WHEN MULTIPLE WL APPS ON AN ANDROID DEVICE
PI06568 DIFFERENT VERSIONS OF A WORKLIGHT APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT GET WR ONG SECURITY TEST IF SECURITY TEST IS CHANGED BETWEEN VERSIONS.
PI05454 WORKLIGHT APPLICATION CENTER ON LIBERTY PROFILE 8.5.5 PRODUCES "LAST-MODIFIED" DATES IN BAD FORMAT.
PI05447 NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION OCCURS WHEN CALLING WL.SERVER.LOGACTIVITY.

Status: Fix Pack


Additional Information: Please see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27028172 for information on installing the fix.
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Idan.  So is PI06519 in the fix pack or not?  It doesn't appear in the list you just provided yet applying the fix pack seems to address the issue.

Comment: It is fixed. It is not in the list.